# Java cannot find or load main class?

Tags: java

I cannot resolve the current issue I am experiencing with Java.
I am familiar with PHP/MySql, but *not* with Java.

Here is my **Java code:**

```
package day1.examples;

public class MyFirstClass
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        System.out.println('Hello World');
    }
}
```

**Problem:** When I go to run the program as Java, I receive the following warning:

[image]

Then, I am receiving the following error in my console: `Error: Could not find or load main class day1.examples.MyFirstClass`
[image]

**Question:** Why is the above code (which I assume is appropriate) not working? Furthermore: Why am I receiving errors?

**Please note:** This is my first day using Java

**EDIT (problems):**[image]

Comment: Try clicking on the "Problems" tab to see the... problems

Comment: Because something is wrong in the configurations. Right click the project , select properties and see java build path. Looks like you don't have the current folder . in the classpath.

Comment: Double qoute your Hello world. Singel is for char and nog string.

Comment: Did you set correctly your `JAVA_HOME` environment variable? Probably that's giving you the error. Or might have something to do not 100% sure

Comment: I have added a photo of the 'problems' tab.

Comment: Unfortunately, I have changed the quotes to doubles, yet the same problem exists.

Comment: Try to create new workspace and create new project in it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove the currently bound JRE from the project & add a new system library using a JRE that exists on your local system.

Comment: This has resolved my issue! Everything is working fine now! Best regards!

Comment: I have added "JRE system library[jdk1.8.0_60]"

Answer (score 1):

The reason it will not work is because the compilation is failing. The reason it is failing it because you used single quotes (') to enclose "Hello World". You should use double quotes (") as you are trying to indicate a String, single quotes are used for individual characters.

Comment: Unfortunately, I have changed the quotes to doubles, yet the same problem exists.

Answer (score 0):

You should tell eclipse which Main calss you want to run. Go to Run --> Run Configurations.. and select the main class to run.

Answer (score 0):

`System.out.println('Hello World');` is not valid Java. Try `System.out.println("Hello World");`